# Django dynamic Form example

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I have a simple requirement for creating a dynamic form in Django - I've seen many examples but they seem to be incomplete, or require more extensive knowledge of Python and Django than I have!  None show how the dynamic portion of the example should be called:

This is the form class with Q1 and Q2 - I place a button on the form to add another
field called Q3 - and then Q4 if pressed again:  I think I got the **init** function semi correct:

```
class testform(forms.Form):
    Q1 = forms.CharField()
    Q2 = forms.CharField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(testform,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.fields['Q%s'%i] = forms.CharField(label='Q%i' % i)
```

I want to place a button on the form to add another
field called Q3 and then Q4 if pressed again.

- How do I call the _*init*_function from the view to add these fields?
- If I use Javascript to add the field dynamically, how do I call **init** so that I can correctly validate with Django when I POST the form?

Comment: this question was answered here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6142025/django-dynamically-add-field-to-a-form

Comment: Yep, that's pretty much what I had. +1 for SO lookups. If you use my code for the Django stuff and his for the JS stuff, I think you'll be set.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To answer your question: Whenever you initialize your form, it calls **init**(). Ex: `form = testform()`. That initializes your form. What I would do here is add some javascript to create these new fields. I'm not sure how familiar you are with javascript, but I'm going to assume you can figure this one out on your own.

As for the validation, this can be done in the form. First though, you'll want to tell it that you've added more fields using `init()`.

```
class TestCharField(forms.CharField):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TestCharField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs) # Needs * and **
    def clean(self, value):
        super(TestCharField, self).clean(value)
        # Do custom validation in here
        return value

class testform(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(testform, self).__init__(args, kwargs)

        # args should be a list with the single QueryDict (GET or POST dict)
        # that you passed it
        for k,v in args[0].items():
            if k.startswith('Q') and k not in self.fields.keys():
                self.fields[k] = TestCharField(initial=v, required=True)
```

You can name your field whatever you want, it doesn't have to be TestCharField. Just make sure to rename it in both places. This will allow you to make as many fields as you like. Let me know if this doesn't quite work for you.

Comment: I tried this code, and noticed that the form was automatically "bound" on creation. I think you need *args and **kwargs in the super() statement.

Answer (score -11):

[Edit]
This was not the best answer, the answer of Bryce is much better. I took the question literally and gave a solution for 4 fields, where a really dynamic form would have been a much more elegant solution.

Please have a look at Bryce' answer.

---

I think I'd define the form with all the possible fields and hide/show them with javascript:

```
class testform(forms.Form)
    Q1 = forms.CharField()
    Q2 = forms.CharField()
    Q3 = forms.CharField()
    Q4 = forms.CharField()
```

HTML:

```
<table>
  {{ testform.as_table }}
</table>
...
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('input[name="q3"]').closest('tr').hide();
        $('input[name="q4"]').closest('tr').hide();
    });
</script>
```

(using JQuery)
And show the fields using your buttons similarly.

Comment: What if there are more than 4? What if there is an arbitrary amount?

Comment: Your limiting yourself and not answering the OP question - He want a dynamic form.  You are providing only a static large form.