# Django ModelForm fields display based on whether related FK fields are used

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I am creating an application where users can set objects and the corresponding data they want to record. Let me give you an example:

```
class vehicle_type(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    int1_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    int1_default = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    int2_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    int2_default = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    float1_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    float1_default = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)

class vehicle(models.Model):
    registration = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    vehicle_type = models.ForeignKey(vehicle_type)
    int1_val = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    int2_val = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    float1_val = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Where the data would be something like this to describe the vehicles:

```
    # pseudo code
    vehicle_type('Car','Seats',4,'Doors',4,'',)
    vehicle_type('Van','Seats',2,'',,'Load',3.2)
```

and then the data on the vehicles would be:

```
    vehicle('ABC 123',1,2,2,) #sports car
    vehicle('DEF 456',1,6,,) #SUV
    vehicle('GHI 789',2,,,1.2) #light van
    vehicle('JKL 246',2,4,3,3.6) #heavy van
```

**My question is how can I make sure that the `vehicleForm` does not display the fields NOT required by the `vehicle_type`?** I know I could pass an instance of the `vehicle_type` to the `vehicleForm` template and only display elements of the `vehicleForm` if they are declared in the `vehicle_type`, but this seems unnecessary and moves logic into the template. (I hope all this makes sense)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass `vehicle_type` to `VehicleForm.__init__()`, and put there some custom logic which would, for example, set widgets of fields that are not required to `HiddenInput`.

Basic example (code is not tested)::

```
class VehicleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, vehicle_type, *args, **kwargs):
        if vehicle_type.name == 'Car':
            self.fields[some_field_for_trucks].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
        super(VehicleForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

And when you instantiate `VehicleForm` in you view, you just pass as a first argument your the `vehicle_type` selected by user.

See examples of dynamic forms:

- [dynamically add field to a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6142025/django-dynamically-add-field-to-a-form)
- [Django dynamic Form example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6154580/django-dynamic-form-example)
- http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/7936 (includes setting widget attributes)

Comment: Thanks! I didn't think to look up `dynamic forms`. I'm afraid `car` is a dynamic variable. I think more then lightly in my situation you'd pass the the key for `vehicle_type` and then test to see if the variable has a name, if it doesn't then you'd hide the input. PS(thanks for the links, I'm reading them at the moment)