# Django MultiWidget format_output method and render method

Tags: django, django-forms

Can anyone explain the format_output method and render method in django Multiwidget.

I have a Select box, a text field for email input and a checkbox. I have created a multiWidget but I want to have a add more feature, like if somebody clicks on the Add More button, javascript will replicate the set of fields that created by the multiWidget.

Also i want to render html like this :

```
<input type = "text" name=textbox_name[] />
```

how can I achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Django [Formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/) and related posts

[dynamically add field to a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6142025/django-dynamically-add-field-to-a-form)