# Django formwizard with formsets and forms on same page

Tags: django, django-forms, django-1.4, django-formwizard

I'm working with Django 1.4 FormWizard (specifically, NamedUrlFormWizard)

first, the basics.  i have a 3 step form wizard i'm building.  The final outcome is along the lines of defining a template, and then choosing some people to use it, and then send them an email.

- Step 1 - enter in basic template data (name, description, etc)
- Step 2 - define a list of N fields, each with their own set of attributes but all identical in structure
- Step 3 - choose one or more users to email, AND customize the contents of this email before saving

so far, in the form wizard:

- Step 1 is a standard Form class, and works just fine.
- Step 2 is a standard Formset class, and works just fine.
- Step 3 is giving me some trouble.  It needs to be a formset (list of email addresses), but also an additional form input field with email text.  I can't figure out how to have both a formset in addition to a non-repeating form input on the same page inside of a form wizard.

in a perfect world, i could define a Formset as just another form field in a Form definition.
ie:

```
class EmailAddressForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField()

class EmailAddressesAndText(forms.Form):
    emailText = forms.Textarea()
    emailAddressFormSet = formset_factory(EmailAddressForm, etc etc)
```

then point my FormWizard page at 'EmailAddressesAndText' and be done with it.  but its not a perfect world.  Any ideas on how I can achieve such a thing?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `get_form()` method of `WizardView` to customize the form for particular step. Refer: [WizardView.get_form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/#django.contrib.formtools.wizard.views.WizardView.get_form). [This answer can help you to add a field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6142025/django-dynamically-add-field-to-a-form)

Another option would be to add the field in formset and through JS disable and hide all instances other than first one.

Comment: The docs have moved (as well as the code)  https://django-formwizard.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gettingstarted.html