# Advanced forms with django-form-builder

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

So, I've been working with the django-forms-builder library. Now, the use case I'm working on says, that using the admin interface, once creates a form asking for details such as the user's name, email, qualifications and so on. Now, the thing is - a user could have multiple qualifications, so the requirement is to display one field, as well as a small "plus" button - clicking that button displays another field, where you could add a second qualification.

Django-forms-builder does everything else I need it to - but this is the only part where I'm stuck. To make matters worse, I'm not a full-blown Django programmer. Would be grateful for any pointers I could get.

EDIT - To clarify, in my project, one defines the form that will be shown to the end user through the Django admin interface. The form will then be displayed to the end user, and if the end user has any additional qualifications s/he'd would like to add, the form that would be rendered, would have that plus button, to add another field.

Comment: I used this [Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6142749/1688590)

Comment: Oh, well - I think I missed out on that one. Thanks a billion! Do you want to turn this into like a regular answer so that I could accept it? Thanks :D

Comment: Never mind. Even that answer I linked is commented as duplicate! The real gem is [this](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2008/nov/09/dynamic-forms/) from Bennett and [this](http://jacobian.org/writing/dynamic-form-generation/) from Kaplan-Moss.

Comment: Haha! Well, it's a small world, I guess. Thanks a lot!