# can I add and modify django form using javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, django

form.py

```
class Upload_Form(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Upload

class Upload_Item_Form(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Upload_Item
        exclude = ('list',)
```

---

models.py

```
class Upload(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    contents=models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title+self.contents

class Upload_Item(models.Model):  
    model_pic = models.FileField(upload_to = 'pic_folder/')
    tag  = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    list=models.ForeignKey(Upload)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.model_pic+self.tag + " (" + str(self.list) + ")"
```

---

.html

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="section">
        {{ Upload_list_form.title }}
        {{ Upload_list_form.contents }}        
    </div>

    <input name="filesToUpload[]" id="filesToUpload" type="file" multiple="" />
    <h2>Image</h2>
    <input type="hidden" id="inputForm"/>    
    <input type="submit" value=" Submit " />
    {{ upload_image_item_formset.management_form }}
    {% for form in upload_image_item_formset.forms %}
    {% endfor %}    
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

I want to using multiple input like *name="filesToUpload[]" id="filesToUpload" type="file" multiple=""*

Add Form and Update Form to write DB 
and display image using local resource like using FileReder in javascript.

Hope it helps. 
Thanks

Comment: dropzonejs is best ...!

Comment: Maybe you need something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6142025/dynamically-add-field-to-a-form ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamically adding a form to a Django formset with Ajax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/501719/dynamically-adding-a-form-to-a-django-formset-with-ajax)