# Django dynamic form field generation

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I want to create the form with 'rooms' field, it is integer field. Depending on numbers of rooms i want to generate two another fields for each room 'extra_adult' and 'extra_children'. And depending on numbers of children i want to generate 'children_age' fields.

I am new to Python and Django and I tried to do like on [DYNAMIC FORM GENERATION](https://jacobian.org/writing/dynamic-form-generation/) post and like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6142025/dynamically-add-field-to-a-form) but i stuck with several question:

1) i have an error `global name 'rooms' is not defined` in forms.py;

2) how should i to `cleaned_data` for `extra_adult`, `extra_children`, `extra_children_age` fields;

3) depending on numbers of children how to add extra_children_age fields.

Here is my form.py

```
class RoomsForm(forms.Form):
        rooms = forms.IntegerField(label=(min_value=1 )

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
                extra_adult = kwargs.pop('extra_adult', 0)
                extra_children = kwargs.pop('extra_children', 0)
                super(HotelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
                for room in rooms:
                        self.fields['adult_%s' % room] = forms.IntegerField(min_value=1 )
                        self.fields['children_%s' % room] = forms.IntegerField(label=(required=False )
```

views.py

```
def bookingForm(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
                form = HotelForm(request.POST, extra_a=request.POST.get('extra_adult'), extra_c=request.POST.get('extra_children'))
                if form.is_valid():
                        rooms = form.cleaned_data['rooms']
                        print "form is valid"
        else:
                form = HotelForm()

        return render(request, 'booking/booking.html', { 'form': form })
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code needs a lot of improvements, I couldn't write the whole thing for you, but here are some places that seems wrong obviously:

1. Your form field definition seems weird: `rooms = forms.IntegerField(label=(min_value=1 )`, take a look at some examples to fix it.
2. Your first error is because you don't have `rooms` variable defined within your constructor. Also, you can't just get value from the field `rooms` like that, all form fields are filled and submitted at the same time, there's no way that fields could cross refer to each other. You might need a separate form to just get the room information.
3. You try to do `kwargs.pop()`, but you feed your form with extra data in the wrong way. To make it work, you should do something like:

`form = HotelForm(request.POST, extra_adult=1, extra_children=2)`

The example you see is a little mis-leading, you shouldn't feed those parameters with `request.POST.get` data, they should be fed with some other sources, that's why I suggest you making the room info in a different form. Once you have that, then feed the result to the second form is much easier.

Comment: I want to do same thing in django rest framework. How can I do that?