# Dynamically generate django forms

Tags: python, django, django-forms, metaprogramming

I'm trying to dynamically generate python classes. Here, a django form.

```
class BankForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField()

for i in range(10):
    setattr(BankForm, 'contact_' + str(i), forms.CharField())
```

But when using the form, only the `name` field shows up. Any advice on how to do it ?

EDIT: Found out about [`modelform_factory`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/models/#django.forms.models.modelform_factory), looks like it's one solution

EDIT2: Even better, looks like there is a [`add_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/formsets/#adding-additional-fields-to-a-formset) method that I can use

Comment: probably because you're setting attributes on `MyForm` and not `BankForm`. But maybe just a typo?

Comment: oops, edited, no, it would have triggered an undefined variable exception

Comment: The `modelform_factory` method is useful for creating model forms, but not really suited for this case where you want to add fields to a regular form. The add_fields` method is for *formsets*,  not forms.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add fields in the form's `__init__` method as follows:

```
class BankForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BankForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for i in range(10):
            self.fields['contact_' + str(i)] = forms.CharField()
```

Comment: thanks, found it was already answered here so it show be closed as duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6142025/dynamically-add-field-to-a-form