# Django add forms to formset in a view

Tags: django, formset

I'm stuck in a design problem.

Imagine an order model and material model,

```
class Material(models.Model):
    material_code = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    standard_price = models.DecimalField()

class Order(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer)


class OrderItems(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order)
    material = models.ForeignKey(Material)
    price = models.DecimalField()
```

In my order detail view, I populate orderitems using inlineformset_factory(Order, OrderItems)

The behaviour I want is below:

If user wants to add more orderitems, I want to redirect user to material listing page, user chooses one or more materials and confirms, then I redirect him to order detail view again with newly added items.

I'm thinking of these to work, like django admin actions with intermediate page.

Before adding new orderitems to order, I also want to set orderitems price from material standard_price, this means I want to modify formsets values before adding it to orderitems.

---

The Question I want to ask here is, is there an easier way to achieve this, it seems, storing formset data to session and repopulating formset with new items wont be easy. I would consider another solutions to this problem.

I dont want the js solutions by the way, imagine a field on my order model, grandtotal, which I may calculate total item amount, with js solutions I may have to do calculation logic with js, user adds an item and change prices then I do the grandtotal calculation with js. This is what I want to avoid.

Comment: The grand total problem is easily avoided. Never accept from a client, what you want control over. So "add to cart" js call only submits item ID and quantity. It receives the new cart totals (calculated at the server) and renders the updated mini cart. Problem solved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the description you've provided, I don't find the usecase for *formsets*.

You simply require a material catalogue page, which lists materials. Each material has the ability to be added to the current cart, which is done through Ajax calls to a url that passes along the PK of the material, so the view for that Ajax call can create the cart and add that material to the cart.

Finally you need an OrderDetail, you need a forloop on all the materials, currently in the users cart.

You can first implement it completely in the database, with relational models defined for Cart, which is actually the Order class you've already implemented.

Then you can add a caching layer to limit writes/deletes/updates to the DB, using django session (this has a performance gain, considering you don't store sessions in your DB!)

So all in all, what you probably need is (I'm using the notion of a cart, to imply that the user can have only one active order, if your requirements are different, it's easily changeable to what you've provided with your Order model):

**Data model:**

```
class Cart:
     user = 1to1(User, related_name='cart') # Can be a FK if you want several active orders
     is_approved = Boolean # To tell if the order is considered Over or is still open
     created_at = DateTimeField
     ...

class Material:
     orders = M2M(Cart, through=CartItem)
     ...

class CartItem:
     cart = FK(Cart)
     material = FK(Material)
     ...
```

**Views:**

```
def list_materials(request):
    returns_rendered_template_with(materials=Material.objects.all())

#Ajax method, called via Post, you probably need a way to also delete, or edit (number of materials to order ?)
def add_material_to_cart(request, material_id):
    cart = Cart.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)
    material = Material.objects.get(pk=material_id)
    CartItem(material=material, cart=cart).save()

def order_detail_view(request):
    cart = user.cart
    cart_items = CartItems.objects.filter(cart=cart)
    returns_rendered_template_with(cart_items=cart_items)
```

**Templates:**

material_list.html

```
....
{% for item in materials %}
       {% show material info, such as price, availability, ... %}
       <button data-pk={{item.pk}}, ...> to call add_material_to_cart </button>
{% endfor %}
```

order_detail.html

```
....
{% for item in cart_items %}
       {% show each cart_item.material and its information + whatever you need %}
{% endfor %}
```

It's the most basic form you can implement the thing, I understood, you want.
You can merge several of this views together, you can implement a "*fully in session*" solution with no need for a Cart and CartItem model, just finalized orders get persisted into I don't know, Bill models ? OrderHistory ? whatever you want.

Comment: A +1 for taking the time and you're almost there. Only get rid of Material. It's not needed and introduces subtle bugs. All items in a cart are perfectly associated with the Many to One in CartItem. Introducing Material allows multiple cart items to be associated with multiple carts, which CartItem itself doesn't allow, until you add the null attribute and then things get funky.

Comment: @Melvyn If he gets rid of Material, he wouldn't be able to have a public *material listings* page. This way, he can list materials for the user to select, on selection, a corresponding *CartItem*'s created which actually belongs only to that user. And meanwhile, IMHO it's more readable to list *Material*s for users, instead of listing *CartItem*s. CartItems are to be listed in the CartDetail view IMHO.

Comment: Also an instance of CartItem can only be associated with a **single** Cart. So each user has a Cart with probably several CartItems in it. On checkout, he can flush the current CartItems (checked_out=True), so the user is faced with a brand new Cart. Materials are used to show the users what's available, Cart and CartItem are used for checkout and billing.

Comment: You're ignoring the Product. A product is the catalog that you call "material listing". There's no need for a product to be associated with an order. If there is no order yet, then what are you going to list? Just think of a real-life supermarket: you put products in the cart and when you've put them at the cash register and paid for them, then you have your order. And yes, a product in a cart is only in a *single* cart, not multiple at the same time. But a *single* cart can contain *multiple* products.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your intentions correctly, you want to create some kind of shopping cart and you do not want to create a database entry for orders that have not been placed yet.

My suggestions would be to create a `Cart` model and an `CartItem` model that stores the information about what items are currently in the cart.
When the customer places the order, you create an new `Order` instance with the corresponding `OrderItem` instances from the cart and its items, and persist that.

`Cart` and `CartItem` can either be Django models stored in the DB, or plain Python classes and serialize them for storage in the session.

Storing them in the DB is probably easier, but will most likely generate more DB queries than a session-based solution. Whether that is an issue depends on your server capacities and expected load. This approach is implemented in [Oscar](http://django-oscar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), an e-commerce framework for Django.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify this by "Adding dynamic fields" to your Order detail form.

When user click an "Add material" button, a new field (say a `<select>` field with list of materials) will be added to form.

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6142025/dynamically-add-field-to-a-form) will help you to achieve your task.

Comment: I didnt get, how this answers my question. Can you elaborate.