# dynamic number of form fields in django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

How to make a `django` form to take a dynamic number of inputs from user in `django`, resulting in dynamic number of form fields.

I need `forms.Form`, not `forms.ModelForm`, because saving to model is not required.

```
class form_name2(forms.Form):
    a1 = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(),
        max_length=100,
        label="1",
        required=False)
    a2 = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(),
        max_length=100,
        label="2",
        required=False)
    a3 = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(),
        max_length=100,
        label="3",
        required=False)
```

Comment: I would look at formsets https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/formsets/

Comment: i want to make n no. of fields according to users requirement, that user can increase,anyone please help me out here

Comment: formsets allow you to make n number of fields otherwise you would need to use javascript

Comment: using formsets i can make dynamic no. of forms...but i need to make dynamic no of fields with auto incremented 1,2,3,4,.... lyk this

Comment: It can be done with formsets. Here are two articles on how to do it with formsets and javascript. Google is your friend, this is a repeat of a question asked many times on here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6142025/dynamically-add-field-to-a-formhttps  //www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2018/05/07/creating-dynamic-forms-django/