# How to update the fields of a model in which user model is inherited with some fields of user model?

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

I am working on a problem where I need to update some fields of user model with one field of the model in which it is inherited. Using updateview with that model shows errors. How am I supposed to do it? thanks in advance.

models.py

```
 class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, null=True)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=Roles)
    verified =models.BooleanField(default = False,blank=True)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='images', blank=True, default='default/testimonial2.jpg')

    def __str__(self):
         return self.user.username
```

views.py

```
    class UserUpdateView(UpdateView):
        fields = ('first_name','last_name','email','photo')
        model = UserProfile
        success_url = reverse_lazy("NewApp:logindex")
```

Comment: Please, share the errors you're facing with the traceback if possible. Also, please be more explicit on what you need/want to do

Answer (score 0):

Use `form_valid` method to do so -

```
class UserUpdateView(UpdateView):
        form_class = UserProfileForm
        model = UserProfile
        success_url = reverse_lazy("NewApp:logindex")
        def form_valid(self, form):
             user_pro = form.instance
             user_pro.user.field_name = form.field_name
             ...
             return super(UserUpdateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Note: If you want to use additional fields in forms you have to create a form say `UserProfileForm` and add their additional fields in forms.py,  see here - [dynamically add field to a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6142025/dynamically-add-field-to-a-form)

Answer (score 0):

There's no inheritance, `User` and `UserProfile` are different models related by a `OneToOneField`. So your view is actually updating two models.

Don't use the generic `UpdateView` which is for updating one model. It's giving you errors because the fields `last_name`, `first_name` and `email` don't exist for `UserProfile`.

Use the plain `View`, create the two model forms (one for `User` and one for `UserProfile`), render them both in your `get()` and `post()` methods and validate them both in your `post()` method.