# save multiple values from a django template

Tags: django

I have a Django template that asks for # of players using a  html form. I pass this variable to the views.py which renders to another template (including the # of players).

The next template shows the same # of input fields to get the name of the players. Here’s the for loop to iterate through the number of players --

```
<form action="name_players" method="POST" class="form-inline">
            {% csrf_token %}

            {% for loop_time in numbers %}
            <input name="name_players[]" type="text" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2" id="inlineFormInputName2" placeholder="name of player...">
            {% endfor %}
            
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Submit</button>
        </form>
```

How should I go about saving these names in an array and returning to the views.py file and then save to a database OR is there a way to do that directly in the template file. thank you!

Comment: Have you tried this method? https://stackoverflow.com/a/6142749/12467282

Comment: A formset could work here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/formsets/

Comment: Thank you crimsonpython24 and Iain -- it looks like from your recommendations that FormSets is the way to go about it.. I'll be studying that and will try to implement it.