# Django Change a form structure by user

Tags: python, django

I am working in Django project that need to have a form that the user can change the structure of the form, for example if the default form is

```
<form>
   <input type="text" value="3">
</form>
```

the user can change it like

```
<form>
   <input type="text" value="5">
   <input type="text" value="6">
</form>
```

The user can add, edit or delete an input. I have seen on internet the django admin site but it change only the data.
Please, Help me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dynamically add field to a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6142025/dynamically-add-field-to-a-form)

Comment: This answer is interesting but i'd like to let the user change the form structure in a special page not directly in the current page like a backoffice