# Dynamic particular field on a form in Django?

Tags: django

I have a form which has more than 10 fields. Now i want a particular field, lets say "requirements". This can be more than one requirement, i can deal with that using rich text editor as ask my user to input all the requirements as a ordered list. But for better user experience i am asking this !

I am gonna keep a button under "requirements" field, so that user can click on this button to get a new field. By this, i want all fields to be combined in a dict like

```
requirements = {'field1','extrafield1'} and etc
```

How to perform this ? I cant user formset ( as am just adding dynamic field not whole form )

How to deal this with django forms ?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and came up with following solution (it's based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6142749/5326234) answer mainly, but I was able to avoid any javascript):

form contains hidden field to store count of `requirement` fields; by default form has one such field, but pressing button `"add_requirement"` increases this count in `TestView.post()`. On `__init__` form adds new fields with proper indexes, if needed, and on `save()` it goes through all requirement indexes to collect values from respective fields.
`TestView.post()` works differently for form's two buttons: `"add_requirement"` just increases fields count and renders form again with added field; default `"submit"` button saves valid form and redirects to `success_url` or re-displays invalid one.

**forms.py**

```
class SimpleForm(forms.Form):   
 
    requirements_count = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), initial=1)     
    stable_field = forms.CharField(label='Stable field', required=False)     
    other_stable_field = forms.CharField(label='Other field', required=False)
    requirements_1 = forms.CharField(label='Requirements', required=False)
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):   
        super(SimpleForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.is_bound:
            requirements_count = int(self.data.get('requirements_count', 1))
        else:
            requirements_count = int(self.initial.get('requirements_count', 1))
        if requirements_count > 1:   
            for index in range(2, requirements_count + 1):
                self.fields.update(
                    {'requirements_' + str(index): 
                    forms.CharField(label='Requirements', required=False)}
                    )
                
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.cleaned_data
        requirements_count = int(form.get('requirements_count', 1))
        requirements_list = []
        for index in range(1, requirements_count + 1):
            requirements = form.get('requirements_' + str(index), '')
            if requirements:            
                requirements_list.append(requirements)
```

**views.py**

```
class TestView(FormView):
    template_name = 'testtemplate.html'
    form_class = SimpleForm
    form = None
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
        
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        request_POST = request.POST
        requirements_count = int(request_POST.get('requirements_count', 1))
        if 'add_requirement' in request_POST:
            new_initial = get_initial(request_POST)
            new_initial['requirements_count'] = requirements_count + 1
            self.form = SimpleForm(initial=new_initial)
            context = self.get_context_data(form=self.form)
            response = render(request, self.template_name, context)
        else:    
            self.form = SimpleForm(data=request_POST)
            context = self.get_context_data(form=self.form)
            if self.form.is_valid():
                response = self.form_valid(self.form)
            else:
                response = render(request, self.template_name, context)  
        return response
        
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()
        return super().form_valid(self.form)

# helper function
def get_initial(previous_data):
    new_initial = {}
    for key, value in previous_data.items():
        if value != '' and key != 'csrfmiddlewaretoken':
            new_initial.update({key: value})
    return new_initial
```

**testtemplate.html**

```
<form action="" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <table border="1">
    {{ form.as_table }}
  </table>
  <input type="submit">
  <input type="submit" name="add_requirement" value="Add another requirement">
  {{ form.non_field_errors }}
</form>
```

I'm in no way Django expert and it may be not the best solution, but it works for me and is relatively simple.