Django dynamically adding integer fields to forms
Hi I have a very simple application that I am making in order to learn Django.
I have a SQLite table that has two columns, the first is the 'id' generated by Django, the second is a charfield containing the name of a product_name.
The way I am trying to get the program to work is as follows:

Get value list of values in the table. This query_set gets assigned to bases
Loop through the each tuple in the bases list and use these values to create form fields. So the product_name will be the Label and the id will be the id of the field. I will later use Jquery on these fields to get the values.

I have the following code:
from django import forms
from django.db import models
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

from .models import Department, Test_list, Products, Current_tests

class Batch(forms.Form):
    bases = Products.objects.all().values_list('product_name','id')
    
    for i in bases: 
        for j in [0,1]:
            bn = i[0]
            bnid = i[1]
            name = forms.IntegerField(label=f"{bn}",widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={"id":bnid}))

The code actually works but instead of getting a number of text inputs equal to the rows in my database, it only shows the last row. I believe this is because while in the loop, I am just simply reassigning a different value "name". The loop itself works and if I print i[0], it will print all the entries in the column. It's to do with the how I am adding the field to the form.
Any help with solving this little problem is much appreciated.

I believe you are correct in the cause of the error.  I think the correct approach would be to override the __init__ method of the form as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/6142749/10951070

There are two ways. The most correct one, in my opinion, would be to work with formsets in this way you can change and save multiple objects with ease:
views.py
def batch(request):
    qs = Products.objects.all()

    ProductsFormSet = formset_factory(Batch, extra=0)
    initial = [{"id": obj.id, "product_name": obj.product_name} for obj in qs]
    formset = ProductsFormSet(initial=initial)

    return render(request, "batch.html", {"formset": formset})

forms.py
class Batch(forms.Form):
    name = forms.IntegerField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Batch, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["name"].label = self.initial["product_name"]
        self.fields["name"].initial = self.initial["id"]

 Second Option 
Is to dynamically create fields in a single form, as you want:
views.py
def batch(request):
    qs = Products.objects.all()
    form = Batch(queryset=qs)

    return render(request, "batch.html", {"form": form})

forms.py
class Batch(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, queryset, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Batch, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for product in queryset:
            self.fields[str(product.id)] = forms.IntegerField(
                label=product.product_name, initial=product.id
            )

